# Using Tikzmark and Arrows

Tags: tikzmark

This is a basic question and I apologize if this program is using the latest version of  the tikzmark library not available in CTAN. I posted as far as I got and also the image I am trying to replicate. Please assist in finishing  the program.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newbox\aebox
\newcommand\aecomment[2][0pt]{%%
  \begin{lrbox}\aebox
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
      \raggedright
      \textcolor{blue}{#2}%%
    \end{minipage}%%
  \end{lrbox}%%
  \raisebox{#1}[\height][0pt]{\usebox{\aebox}}}

\begin{document}
For $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$, we have

\begin{align*}
        f(x+h)&=\dfrac{1}{x+h} \\
\shortintertext{then}\\
                    f(x+h)-f(x)&=\dfrac{1}{x+h}-\dfrac{1}{x} \\ \\
                           &=\dfrac{1}{x+h} \cdot \textcolor{red} 
   {\dfrac{\tikzmarknode{C}{x}}{x}}-\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot \textcolor{red} 
   {\dfrac{x+h}{x+h}} && \aecomment[1.3ex]{\textcolor{red}{\tikzmarknode{A} 
   {}Multiplying by $1$ to get a common denominator}}\\
   \end{align*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red] ([yshift=3pt,xshift=-5pt]A.west) -- ++(-7pt,0pt)-- ++ (0pt,7pt);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

I am trying to recreate

[image]

I keep compiling errors each attempt to recreate the arrows.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The newest tikzmarklibrary is now for a while in the standard TeX distributions, so everything is fine, and it is really easy to draw the arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newbox\aebox
\newcommand\aecomment[2][0pt]{%%
  \begin{lrbox}\aebox
    \begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
      \raggedright
      \textcolor{blue}{#2}%%
    \end{minipage}%%
  \end{lrbox}%%
  \raisebox{#1}[\height][0pt]{\usebox{\aebox}}}

\begin{document}
For $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$, we have

\begin{align*}
        f(x+h)&=\dfrac{1}{x+h} \\
\shortintertext{then}\\
                    f(x+h)-f(x)&=\dfrac{1}{x+h}-\dfrac{1}{x} \\ \\
                           &=\dfrac{1}{x+h} \cdot \textcolor{red} 
   {\dfrac{\tikzmarknode{C}{x}}{x}}-\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot \textcolor{red} 
   {\dfrac{x\tikzmarknode{C'}{+}h}{x+h}} && \aecomment[1.3ex]{\textcolor{red}{\tikzmarknode{A} 
   {}Multiplying by $1$ to get a common denominator}}\\
   \end{align*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red,-latex] ([yshift=3pt,xshift=-5pt]A.west) -- ++(-7pt,0pt)-- ++ (0pt,12pt)
coordinate (aux)-| (C.north);
\draw[red,-latex] (aux) -| (C'.north);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes I am getting the same error. I don't understand why? The error is that the shape C' is  not known and I have the tikzmarknode label and copy from your program

Comment: @MathScholar I do not get any error (obviously, otherwise I wouldn't have posted this code). Did you update your TeX distribution? (I am using the official version of `tikzmark` that comes with the standard TeX distributions and is also available from CTAN.)

Comment: I guess I have to update and yes I see your output but why it work from the node A I posted.

Comment: I tried it on a different program from the past and it compiled so it is not an update issue. Very strange but this has happened before.

Comment: yes I ran it separately and got your output but when I run this as part of my larger program I get an error. I don't know what to say but the code is rejected in the larger program.

Comment: @MathScholar Sorry to hear that but I cannot do much except for providing complete codes that run through. (My [crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen.)

Comment: I think there is an incompatibility issue with the packages I am using in the larger program? I did not design tikzmark but notice there are others who ran into this problem. Thank s for your help Marmot

Comment: I got rid of package flexisym and it went through. I don't know what this package is exactly. Last time it was pgfplots. Not pulling your leg. This is a head scratching . Try inserting \usepackage{flexisym} on your end and see if you have the same situation

Comment: Why is there a `{}` in `\aecomment[1.3ex]{\textcolor{red}{\tikzmarknode{A}{}Multiplying by $1$ to get a common denominator}}`\\?

Comment: @MathScholar If you post the full preamble (preferably in form of a new question since I will be offline now) I guess somebody will be able to help,

Comment: @manooooh I don't know, I really focussed on the arrows, thanks for checking, will look at it in a few hours...

Comment: @MArmot hi Marmot  same Preamble as above except when I add the package flexisym the error occurs. I am curious it that happens for you? The package was apart of a larger template. I have your program running, so THANK YOU but just want to let you know what I ran into

Comment: @MathScholar Yes, it does. I really encourage you to post a minimal question with that content (I am about to start driving) and hope that Joseph Wright will see it. (I am already scared by the statement in the manual "For now, the user’s guide is in breqn.". `breqn` is known to modify catcodes. You could *try* if [these tricks here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460750/121799) help, but there is a chance that you get ultimately told not to use the package.)

Comment: I will do now. Drive safely!

Comment: @manooooh You have a good point, `\tikzmarknode{A}{}` just creates an empty node. In principle, this is not what `\tikzmarknode` is made for, I think. On the other hand. it is also not wrong, strictly speaking.