# How to create an arrow from one number to another number (below a number list)

Tags: math-mode, arrows

How to create an arrow from one number to another number (below a number list), similar to the picture below?

[image: Example]

Comment: HI, i suggest to use `\tikzmark` as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461217/using-tikzmark-and-arrows

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You can define Ti*k*Z nodes and use them later in a `tikzpicture`. You need to use the `remember` tag so that Ti*k*Z remembers your node after the local environment ends. In your `tikzpicture` you then need to use the `overlay` tag, so that the image can overlay other parts of your document.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mynode}[2]{%
    \tikz[remember picture, baseline=(#1.base)]{%
        \node(#1)[inner sep = 0, text = #2]{#1};%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    $\mynode{130}{blue}, 131, 132, 133, \mynode{134}{red}, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140$
    
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[->, shorten <=.05cm, shorten >=.05cm]
            (134)
            |-
            ++(0,-0.5)
            -|(130);
\end{document}
```

[image: numbers]

Answer (score 3):

For TikZ is written the library `tikzmark` which is dedicated for such cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\[
\tikzmarknode{A}{\color{blue}130}, 131, 132, 133, \tikzmarknode{B}{\color{red}134}, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->, shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
            (B) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (A);
\vspace{1ex} % for more vertical space for arrow
\]
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `pstricks` solution, using a simple `array`: just define the numbers to be connected as `\rnodes` and connect them with `\pcbar`.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

    \[ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}\begin{array}{*{11}{c}}
      \rnode{A}{\color{blue}130}, & 131, & 132, & 133, & \rnode{B}{\color{red}134}, & 135, & 136, & 137, & 138, & 139, & 140
    \end{array} \pcbar[linecolor =SteelBlue!80, arrowinset=0.12, arrows=->, angle=-90, nodesep=1.5ex](B)(A) \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]