# Semicolon in node label in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, punctuation, breqn

I am trying to have a label with the text "I(X;Y)". However, it fails to compile due to the semicolon. Is there any way to escape the semicolon?

Edit: The following code works perfectly

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0){$I(X;Y)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, in my document I had `\usepackage{breqn}` and compilation does not complete when used with it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{breqn} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0){$I(X;Y)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0){$I(X;Y)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` compiles without problems. Which errors do you get? Could you please provide us with a minimal document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and illustrates the problem?

Comment: Thank you! I did not need `breqn` in my document and I removed it and it worked perfectly. But still, I would like to know why this doesn't work and a possible workaround while using it.

Comment: In my answer to the linked question I show how to cope with the semicolon. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460746/4427